# Find all value pairs with different signs

Tags: r

There is a vector with values of different signs (the positive values and the negative values)

```
v <- c(-1, 3, 4, -5, 6, -8, 9, -10, -11, -12, 14, -15, -16, -17)
```

I want to find out all the pairs of values with different signs, e.g.:

-1 and 3, -1 and 4, -1 and 9 ...

3 and -5, 3 and -8, 3 and -10 ...

so on and forth, and neglect the pairs with the same values (for example we have -1 and 3,and 3 and -1, we discard 3 and -1).

How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

A tidyverse version of the above might work as follows:

1. Expand grid
2. Filter so that signs of columns are unequal
3. Sort rows such that lower number is always in first column
4. Filter unique columns

```r
library(tidyverse)
sort_row <- function(val1, val2) {
  if (val1 <= val2) {
    return(tibble(v1 = val1, v2 = val2))
  } else {
    return(tibble(v1 = val2, v2 = val1))
  }
}
v <- c(-1, 3, 4, -5, 6, -8, 9, -10, -11, -12, 14, -15, -16, -17)


expand_grid(v1 = v, v2 = v) %>% 
  filter(sign(v1) != sign(v2)) %>% 
  pmap_dfr(~sort_row(.x, .y)) %>% 
  unique()
#> # A tibble: 45 x 2
#>       v1    v2
#>    <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1    -1     3
#>  2    -1     4
#>  3    -1     6
#>  4    -1     9
#>  5    -1    14
#>  6    -5     3
#>  7    -8     3
#>  8   -10     3
#>  9   -11     3
#> 10   -12     3
#> # ... with 35 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

May be this works

```
subset( setNames(expand.grid(split(v, sign(v))), c('V1', 'V2')), abs(V1) != V2)
```

Comment: and what if we keep the pairs with the same values?

Comment: Just remove the `subset` wrapper i.e. `setNames(expand.grid(split(v, sign(v))), c('V1', 'V2'))`

Comment: it seems that these two give the same result

Comment: @TianjianQin those are different as the `subset` removes the same abs value rows

Comment: is there a function similar to `expand.grid()` but finds all the permutations rather than combos?

Comment: There is one with `combn`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try the code below

```
> subset(as.data.frame(t(combn(v, 2))), V1 * V2 < 0)
    V1  V2
1   -1   3
2   -1   4
4   -1   6
6   -1   9
10  -1  14
15   3  -5
17   3  -8
19   3 -10
20   3 -11
21   3 -12
23   3 -15
24   3 -16
25   3 -17
26   4  -5
28   4  -8
30   4 -10
31   4 -11
32   4 -12
34   4 -15
35   4 -16
36   4 -17
37  -5   6
39  -5   9
43  -5  14
47   6  -8
49   6 -10
50   6 -11
51   6 -12
53   6 -15
54   6 -16
55   6 -17
56  -8   9
60  -8  14
64   9 -10
65   9 -11
66   9 -12
68   9 -15
69   9 -16
70   9 -17
73 -10  14
78 -11  14
82 -12  14
86  14 -15
87  14 -16
88  14 -17
```

---

Or, a longer option

```
do.call(
    rbind,
    sapply(
        seq_along(v),
        function(k) {
            p <- v[seq_along(v) >= k & sign(v) == -sign(v[k])]
            if (length(p)) {
                data.frame(V1 = v[k], V2 = p)
            }
        }
    )
)
```

which gives

```
    V1  V2
1   -1   3
2   -1   4
3   -1   6
4   -1   9
5   -1  14
6    3  -5
7    3  -8
8    3 -10
9    3 -11
10   3 -12
11   3 -15
12   3 -16
13   3 -17
14   4  -5
15   4  -8
16   4 -10
17   4 -11
18   4 -12
19   4 -15
20   4 -16
21   4 -17
22  -5   6
23  -5   9
24  -5  14
25   6  -8
26   6 -10
27   6 -11
28   6 -12
29   6 -15
30   6 -16
31   6 -17
32  -8   9
33  -8  14
34   9 -10
35   9 -11
36   9 -12
37   9 -15
38   9 -16
39   9 -17
40 -10  14
41 -11  14
42 -12  14
43  14 -15
44  14 -16
45  14 -17
```

Comment: how to get all permutations? for example we have both `-1, 3` and `3, -1`, both `4, -11` and `-11, 4`

Comment: well, let's say the result is `combos`, we can simply `rbind` `combos` and `combos[c(2, 1)]`, it seems that there is no such function in R itself

Comment: @TianjianQin You can try `u <- t(combn(v, 2)); subset(as.data.frame(rbind(u,u[,2:1])), V1 * V2 < 0)`